# How to get the @SuppressWarnings warning name for an IntelliJ warning?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compiler-warnings, lombok, suppress-warnings

IntelliJ wrongly tells me that a field initializer is redundant, but it is in fact used by Lombok's `@Builder.Default`.

I would like to suppress this warning using `@SuppressWarnings` but I don't know what the warning is called (alt-enter also gives me no option to suppress). How can I find a warning's name in IntelliJ?

Comment: Maybe `@SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")`? Alt-Enter worked for me

Comment: @Vic: Thanks, that works, but Alt-Enter doesn't work, it only gives me an option to remove the initializer.

Comment: When you press "Alt-Enter" and "Remove redundant initializer" suggestion appears, press the "right" button on the keyboard and another set of options appears with "Suppress for field" being one of them. Worked for me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By putting your cursor on the warning and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, it should open up a menu. In this menu, there should be an option to remove the field. Navigate to this option and press <kbd>→</kbd>. This opens up a sub-menu which contains the options to suppress the warning. By doing so, IntelliJ will generate the appropriate annotation.

In your case, the annotation should probably be along the lines of `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` or `@SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment")`.

Comment: I highly recommend not trying this on newer versions of IntelliJ IDEA. After pressing `→`, the sub-menu that pops up contains eight different options. None of them adds an annotation to the code, but some just mess up with the IDE settings in a way that is very annoying to revert.

Comment: @GOTO0 What version of IntelliJ did you use? I used 2020.3 which looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/um7gnSf . Clicking the highlighted option does exactly what's described in my answer.

Comment: I am also using 2020.3. The options are the same as in your image :/

Answer (score 6):

Looks like there is another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47959693/266531) here for how to suppress unused methods or members, which is to add the annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`. Or, if you want to suppress a local variable, then you'd have to insert a line comment `// noinspection unused`, like

```
// noinspection unused
long int i = 0;
```

To answer your question of, "How can I find a warning's name in Intellij?", I found a web page from a James Roper who lists out all the Intellij warning keywords paired with a brief definition.
https://jazzy.id.au/2008/10/30/list_of_suppresswarnings_arguments.html

For example, the one I was after was

> Redundant local variable =    UnnecessaryLocalVariable

That list in Roper's page only covers the special warnings invented by JetBrains. The warning you need, "unused", has been around for a long time and pre-dates IntelliJ. Some are a part of the java compiler.  For a list of the javac warnings, I found from https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/09/what-is-suppresswarnings-annotation-in-java-unchecked-raw-serial.html that you can run  `javac -X`. For Java 1.8, I found

```
all,auxiliaryclass,cast,classfile,deprecation,dep-ann,divzero,empty,fallthrough,finally,options,overloads,overrides,path,processing,rawtypes,serial,static,try,unchecked,varargs
```

That still doesn't lead us to `unused`. The `unused` warning came from Eclipse and is also supported by Intellij. For a list of Eclipse warnings, see https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-suppress_warnings.htm

That pages contains

- all = to suppress all warnings
- boxing = to suppress warnings relative to boxing/unboxing operations
- cast = to suppress warnings relative to cast operations
- dep-ann = to suppress warnings relative to deprecated annotation
- deprecation = to suppress warnings relative to deprecation
- fallthrough = to suppress warnings relative to missing breaks in switch statements
- finally = to suppress warnings relative to finally block that don't return
- hiding = to suppress warnings relative to locals that hide variable
- incomplete-switch = to suppress warnings relative to missing entries in a switch statement (enum case)
- javadoc = to suppress warnings relative to javadoc warnings
- nls = to suppress warnings relative to non-nls string literals
- null = to suppress warnings relative to null analysis
- rawtypes = to suppress warnings relative to usage of raw types
- resource = to suppress warnings relative to usage of resources of type Closeable
- restriction = to suppress warnings relative to usage of discouraged or forbidden references
- serial = to suppress warnings relative to missing serialVersionUID field for a serializable class
- static-access = to suppress warnings relative to incorrect static access
- static-method = to suppress warnings relative to methods that could be declared as static
- super = to suppress warnings relative to overriding a method without super invocations
- synthetic-access = to suppress warnings relative to unoptimized access from inner classes
- sync-override = to suppress warnings because of missing synchronize when overriding a synchronized method
- unchecked = to suppress warnings relative to unchecked operations
- unqualified-field-access = to suppress warnings relative to field access unqualified
- unused = to suppress warnings relative to unused code and dead code